# Log4j2 - How to add message and log level to keyValuePair value

Tags: java, log4j2

Desired Outcome:
I would like my logs to store the below data in the keyValuePair:
"@timestamp" : "05-11-2020 17:24:29.895",
"@Message" : "Log Message",
"@LogLevel" : "INFO"

Issue i'm having is in the KeyValuePair section i am unable to get the event lookup to pull through the message field of the log and the level of the log.

Below is my config file currently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration package="log4j2.test" status="info">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleRuleLogger" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <JsonLayout complete="false" compact="false" properties="true" objectMessageAsJsonObject="true">
                <KeyValuePair key="@timestamp" value="${date:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}" />
                <KeyValuePair key="@Message" value="${message}" />
                <KeyValuePair key="@LogLevel" value="${level}" />
            </JsonLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.reflections" level="off" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleRuleLogger" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleRuleLogger"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I have also tried the following changes to KeyValuePair:

```
 <KeyValuePair key="@Message" value="$${message}" />
 <KeyValuePair key="@LogLevel" value="$${level}" />
```

and

```
 <KeyValuePair key="@Message" value="$${event:message}" />
 <KeyValuePair key="@LogLevel" value="$${event:level}" />
```

Any help would be appriciated i know i can just create my own map and pass it into the message with these fields but that isn't the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

In log4j-core-2.11.2 version you may need to this :

put attribute `ip` into MDC:

```
MDC.put("ip","127.0.0.1");
```

```
<JsonLayout compact="true" eventEol="true">
    <KeyValuePair key="ip" value="$${ctx:ip}"/>
</JsonLayout>
```